# Copying XY to clipboard using Python Add-In (ArcMap)

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7, python-addin

I am trying to create a simple tool to copy XY from where i click the mouse button. What i have done already is:

1. create add-in files using Python Add-In Wizard
2. create toolbar and tool inside it

in *.py file i got:

```python
import arcpy

import pythonaddins

import win32clipboard as clipboard


class p_tool(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.shape = "NONE" 

def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
    button = 1
    shift  = 2
    clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    xy = str(x)+' '+str(y)
    clipboard.SetClipboardData(xy, clipboard.CF_TEXT)
    clipboard.closeClipboard()
    message = xy
    pythonaddins.MessageBox(message, "My Coordinates", 0)
```

About win32clipboard - i tested in in python windon in ArcMap and I am able to import it and openclipboard() but emptyclipboard() does not work and gives me that error:

File "", line 1, in 
error: (1418, 'EmptyClipboard', 'Thread does not have a clipboard open.')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses the approach of calling a subprocess and piping the text to the clipboard.

A couple of things to note:

1. I use the *onMouseUpMap* event, this returns the XY coordinates in map units.
2. I placed a comma between the numbers so there is no space between them.
3. Wrapped the code up in a try-except to capture any failures.

```py
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import subprocess
class p_tool(object):
    """Implementation for pythonaddintest_addin.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE"

def onMouseUpMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
    try:
        xy = str(x)+','+str(y)
        command = "echo " + xy + " | clip"
        i=subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
        message = xy
        pythonaddins.MessageBox(message, 'My Coordinates', 0)
    except Exception as e:
        pythonaddins.MessageBox(str(e),"Error",0)
```